# Button (clicked) work one time

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
   namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private int n = 0;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ++n;
            Button1.Text = n.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

'n' change one time

Thank`s
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Do some basic reading about _ASP.NET_

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it static

```
 namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static int n = 0;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ++n;
            Button1.Text = n.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare **n** as static variable and check. It will work

```
private static int n = 0;
```